# codeigniter3: display username and logout after successfully login

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

How to display username and logout after successfully login in header view page?
How to get session data with this and display it in view page?

Controller

```
public function login() {

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

        $postDatas = $this->input->post();
        $postData = str_replace (" ", "", $postDatas);

        $this->load->model('Log');
        $response = $this->Log->login($postData);       

        if($response['success_message']) {
            //create session  
            $user = set_user_session($response['data']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('userdata', $user);    
            $sessionData = $this->session->userdata('userdata');    

            redirect('');   
        }
        else
        {           
            $sessionData = $this->session->userdata('userdata');
            $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>';
            $msg .= 'Mobile Number / Email or password does not match';
            $msg .= '</div>';
            if($postData['userType'] == 2)
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('loginMessage', $msg);            
                redirect('sign-in');
            }           
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: i updated code once check@mrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a session like this:

```
$user_data["user_name"] = "mrid";
$user_data["param1"] = "param1 value";
$user_data["param2"] = "param2 value";

$this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
```

You can simply access the session params like:

```
$user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];
$param1_val = $_SESSION['param1'];
$param2_val = $_SESSION['param2'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have create a session then you can use it anywhere in the codeigniter, You can also get the values in the view file use the following code to access session.

```
$this->session->userdata['session_name']['session_element'];
```

This will allow you to access particular session element.

I hope this will help you.